# R - Trycatch is saving warning instead of returning function output

Tags: r, for-loop, warnings

I am trying to download records from twitter using `rtweet`. One issue with this is the twitter server needs to wait 15minutes every 18000 records. So, after record number 18000, I receive a data frame with all the records and a nice warning telling me to wait for a bit. `search_tweets` has an function argument to download more than 18000 records called `retryonratelimit`. However, this isnt working so I am exploring other options.

I have produced a function, incorporating `tryCatch` to address this. However, when the warning at 18000 records pops up, tryCatch is saving the warning rather than the data frame which should be spit out before the warning. Something it would not do if 17999 records were downloaded

```
library(rtweet)
library(RDCOMClient)
library(profvis)

TwitScrape = function(SearchTerm){
  ReturnDF = tryCatch({
    TempList=NULL
    Temp = search_tweets(SearchTerm,n=18000)
    TempList = list(as.data.frame(Temp), SearchTerm)
    return(TempList)
    },
    warning = function(TempList){
      Comb=NULL
      MAXID = min(TempList[[1]]$status_id)
      message("Delay for 15 minutes to accommodate server download limits")
      pause(901)
      TempWarn = search_tweets(TempList[[2]],n=18000, max_id=MAXID)
      TempWarn = as.data.frame(TempWarn)
      Comb = rbind(TempList[[1]], TempWarn)
      CombList = list(Comb, TempList[[2]])
      return(CombList)
    }
      )
  }

Searches = c("#MUFC","#LFC", "#MCFC")
TestExpandList=NULL
TestExpand=NULL
TestExpand2=NULL
for (i in seq_along(Searches)){
  TestExpandList = TwitScrape(SearchTerm =  Searches[i])
  TestExpand = TestExpandList[[1]]
  TestExpand$Cat = Searches[i]
  TestExpand$DownloadDate = Sys.Date()
  TestExpand2 = rbind(TestExpand2, TestExpand)
}
```

I hope this makes sense. If I can offer any more information please let me know.  In summary, why is `tryCatch` saving my warning rather than the data frame I want?

Comment: Are you sure `retryonratelimit` is not working?

Comment: Try to condense your problem into a minimal reproducible example. This will make your question much more clear and easier to understand, therefore many ppl will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you would like to achieve, but it seems you are using `tryCatch` with a wrong understanding.

The argument in the warning-handler `warning = function(TempList)` is the warning itself, i.e. you have named it `TempList`, but that doesn't mean it will become your `TempList` variable, it will still just pass the `warning` into the handler.

Your function `TwitScrape` is returning `ReturnDF` by convention, as you are not properly returning anything, I guess that is still what you want and ok.

I would try to re-structure your solution without `tryCatch`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. RolandASc, you were right. I went back to the drawing board. See the working TwitScrape function below:

```
TwitScrape = function(SearchTerm){
  DF=NULL
  DF = search_tweets(SearchTerm,n=18001)
  Warn = warnings()
if (names(Warn[1]) == "Rate limit exceeded - 88"){
  message("paused")
  pause(910)
  DF2 = search_tweets(SearchTerm,n=18000, max_id = min(DF$status_id))
  DF3 = rbind(DF, DF2)
  return(DF3)
  }
else {
  return(DF)
  }}
```